# TChart - Dont plot values that are less than 0?

Tags: delphi, charts

**Introduction**

I am using the TChart component and am finding the options rather confusing and hard to find what I need.

The Left Axis of the chart has a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 5000, the Bottom Axis has a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 52 (weeks in a year).

In my chart I have 2 series that are populated based on values from a record I have created which can be edited at runtime, everything is working good so far.

**Problem**

Take a look at the below image of part of the chart filled with some random values:

[image]

I am not sure if such an option exists or not, but notice from week 4 onwards where no values have been added there is a solid red line.

I don't want the chart to plot values that are less than 0, so in this example from week 4 onwards there should be no more lines (I can confirm that from week 4 onwards I have the values set at -1)

Week 1 to 4 does not show this bottom red line, obviously because the values are greater than 0 and are therefore plotted above the line, but this should make my problem a bit more clearer.

So, how do I prevent the chart from plotting / drawing values that are less than 0, importantly for the Bottom Axis of the chart?

I am sure there must be a simple option somewhere, I just cannot find it if there is one as I am not too familiar with the TChart Component.

Comment: What is the chart supposed to do with the extra values instead? What happens, for instance, if there's a positive value added in week 9 - what should happen with weeks 5-8?

Comment: In my Jedi TJvChart I would say you plot `NaN` instead of the negative value to omit it completely. (If X < 0 then X = NaN). I am not sure if Teechart has the same "NaN semantics"

Comment: @KenWhite you're right I never give that any though if I am honest. I have just been testing with LU RD's answer and I see your point. I think I am just going to leave it as it is, I might have a look at the TJvChart as Warren pointed out but don't really want to change it just yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the possibility when adding values to a series to add them as null.

This will prevent them from showing.

Ken is correct saying that a tricky situation is to handle a single value surrounded by null values.
Picking another series type than `FastLine` and show dots as well as lines might work better.

For a `FastLine` series to show gaps, set:

```
Series1.IgnoreNulls := False;
```

And to discriminate values below zero:

```
if (y < 0) then
  Series1.AddNullXY(x, y, '')
else
  Series1.AddXY(x, y, '');
```

Comment: `AddNullXY` was what I was looking for, I tried it out and it didn't work as expected as has been mentioned. I will accept this answer but have decided to keep the chart as is.

Comment: Later versions of TChart have deprecated the IgnoreNulls property and replaced it with the new TreatNulls property. In that case you probably want TreatNulls := tnDontPaint

Answer (score 1):

```
if y < 0 then
   LineSeries1.AddXY(x, y, '', clNone)
else
   LineSeries1.AddXY(x, y, '', clRed);
```